# Collapse Accordions in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

Using the `<Accordion>` - Tag in react implicitly generates bootstrap-elements from which I don't know how to access them.

The structure is the following:

```
return (
<Card>
<Accordion>
<Accordion.Item eventKey={uniqueAccordionItemKey}>
<Accordion.Header>
</Accordion.Header>
<Accordion.Body>
</Accordion.Body>
</Accordion.Item>
</Accordion>
</Card>
);
```

From this many Accordions are being generated. I want a possibility to collapse all of them. How do I do so?

I tried to manipulate the css-attributes using show and collapse as attributes but this turned out just hiding the content and not collapsing the Accordion.
Also manipulating the aria-expanded attribute inside the Accordion.Item did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/components/accordion/#accordion

You can control the accordion items using the `activeKey` prop on the `Accordion` in combination with the `eventKey` on the `Accordion.Item`

Comment: This turned out to be the best solution. Thank you very much!